# Search elements in Python list, item by item, and create a new list based on conditional statement

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I cannot seem to figure out an iterative loop that will do what I need in this scenario.

I have a list:

```
seqlist1 = ['C', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T']
```

And another, empty list:

```
seqlist2 = []
```

I want to be able to check item by item in the `seqlist1` list if a specific letter is present and if that specific letter is present, insert it's complement letter at the same index in the empty list `seqlist2`.

So far, I've tried the following but I know it's not right:

```
seqlist1 = ['C', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T']

seqlist2 = []

for index, item in enumerate(seqlist1):
    if item in seqlist1 == 'A':
        seqlist2.append('T')
    if item in seqlist1 == 'T':
        seqlist2.append('A')
    if item in seqlist1 == 'C':
        seqlist2.append('G')
    if item in seqlist1 == 'G':
        seqlist2.append('C')

print seqlist2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the desired result for the example case?

Comment: @CristiFati yes, messing around with the Rosalind Bioinformatics tutorials....:)

Comment: @StefanPochmann The desire result would be a list that is known as a DNA complement (i.e. a new list that has the nucleotide base pairs or complements for the letters in the first list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct but your syntax is wrong.

Just iterate over `seqlist1` and check each item, using the syntax
`for item in seqlist1`. Then, you compare if `item` equals `'T'`, `'A'`, `'G'` or `'C'` using `if item == 'A'`.

```
seqlist1 = ...

seqlist2 = []

for item in seqlist1:
    if item == 'A':
        seqlist2.append('T')
    if item == 'T':
        seqlist2.append('A')
    if item == 'C':
        seqlist2.append('G')
    if item == 'G':
        seqlist2.append('C')

print seqlist2
```

<sub>(My goal here is not to give you fancy one-line codes, but a code you can understand as you're a beginner)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't think anybody fully explained your mistake:

In Python you can for example write `5 <= x <= 10` and Python will do what you think it would do - tell you whether x is between 5 and 10. It's basically the same as `(5 <= x) and (x <= 10)`. You can read about such comparison chaining [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Now you wrote `item in seqlist1 == 'A'`. But `in` and `==` are comparisons and your expression actually means `(item in seqlist1) and (seqlist1 == 'A')`. Of course the first half will always be True, and the second half will always be False. The `and` then makes the whole thing False.

Let's confirm that I'm not lying :-). After the above explanation, it should be clear why this is True:

```
>>> 'a' in 'bar' == 'bar'
True
```

And it should be clear why parenthesising the left or right part fails:

```
>>> ('a' in 'bar') == 'bar'
False

>>> 'a' in ('bar' == 'bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    'a' in ('bar' == 'bar')
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `if item == 'A'`... or a nicer way might be to use a dict mapping the letters to swap:

```
d = {"A":"T","T":"A","C":"G","G":"C"}

seqlist1 = ['C', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T']

# swap A -> T, T -> A ...
print([d[k] for k in seqlist1])
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, I make a special effort when you are around ;)

Comment: Nice! You are indeed improving!

Answer (score 3):

```
from string import maketrans
tab = maketrans("ATGC","TACG")
seqlist1 = ['C', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T']
seq_str = "".join(seqlist1)
print seq_str.translate(tab)
```

is a good way to do this , especially since I assume the list is initially in string form anyway.

I wrote this since it is fast and it makes good use of library built-ins.  it is also fairly readable(at least imho).  and I assume that this is for a bioinformatics course in which you really just want the inverted sequence to do some secondary processing on. (if this is actually a intro to programming assignment your teacher may not appreciate this solution)

if you wanted to have pairs of `(orig,new)` you can easily zip them together

```
print zip(seq_str,seq_str.translate(tab))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough

```
seqlist1 = ....
mapping = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G'}
seqlist2 = [mapping[item] for item in seqlist1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take an entirely different approach here and use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) after a call to [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

In Python 2.x:

```
from string import maketrans
''.join(seqlist1).translate(maketrans('ATCG','TAGC'))
```

In Python 3.x:

```
''.join(seqlist1).translate(str.maketrans('ATCG','TAGC'))
```

To convert the resulting string back to a list of characters, you can just pass it as an argument to the built-in list type.

```
>>> list('ATCG')
['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
```

Comment: funny I had the same thought :P (+1 esp. for showing how to do it in 3+ :P)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes. Unfortunately, I noticed this after I finished my answer. :( But +1 to you too.

Answer (score 1):

```
seqlist2 = ['ATCG'['TAGC'.index(c)] for c in seqlist1]
```

Or:

```
seqlist2 = map(dict('AT TA CG GC'.split()).get, seqlist1)
```

Comment: That dict string split part is pretty fancy. I wouldn't have thought of that, and honestly I didn't even know it was possible, I thought you could only do it with tuples! +1 :)